# Is it safe to read from and write to an array at the same time Go

Tags: go, concurrency

Would this be safe to use? it doesnt matter if the read routine reads a partially updated array, but i need it to have all values intact. All 3 routines run in a loop

```
var arr [100]byte

go ReadFrom(arr)
go ReadFrom(arr)
go WriteTo(arr)
```

Comment: No data structures in Go are safe for concurrent reads and writes.

Comment: What would be the worst thing that could happen? the memory can't physically be read and written to at the same time, so my instincts tell me the content of the bytes should be safe, although you couldn't guarantee that the whole array is completely updated

Comment: Anything could happen. There are no benign data races: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Pownyan, no, not safe, as mentioned by JimB in the comments. You need mutex locks to make this safe: https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex

Example: https://gobyexample.com/mutexes

Comment: The problem is that i need to do the write part many times a second, and mutexes take extra time and processing power. i know how to use them, but they are slow... As the data is only a array of byte, and i don't see any reason whatsoever for the compiler to generate code that partially writes a single byte I can't see any possible problem with it (although I could be wrong)

Comment: Check here: https://golang.org/doc/faq#atomic_maps
I would be concerned about that part: ...This was not an easy decision, however, since it means uncontrolled map access can crash the program..."

Comment: I've read up on the issue a bit more, and found this which explains a serious problem that could occur: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/19rtbn/benign_data_races_what_could_possibly_go_wrong/c8qwuuc/ . Thanks for taking your time to help me

Answer (score 0):

No, its not safe, you will need to use [sync](https://godoc.org/sync) package Mutex or `Waitgroup` depends on the type of the solution flow, i recommend `Mutex` since it is cheaper than other `channel` based solutions.

please check the example [here](https://gobyexample.com/mutexes).